# Threads deadlocking

Tags: ruby, multithreading, deadlock

G'day,

I was trying to do a simple multithreading experiment using ruby 1.9.3.

The code:

```
require 'thread'

ary = *0..10 

res = 0
mutex = Mutex.new
#cv = ConditionVariable.new

ary.each do |x|
    p "Iteration no. #{x}"
    t = Thread.new do
        p "Thread taking care of #{x}"
        mutex.synchronize do 
            #cv.wait(mutex)
            res += x
            t.stop
        end
    end
end

Thread.list.each do |t| t.join; end
puts res
```

The call

```
brode@curral:~/coding$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
brode@curral:~/coding$ ruby mt.rb
"Iteration no. 0"
"Iteration no. 1"
"Iteration no. 2"
"Iteration no. 3"
"Iteration no. 4"
"Thread taking care of 2"
"Thread taking care of 1"
"Thread taking care of 0"
"Thread taking care of 3"
"Iteration no. 5"
"Thread taking care of 4"
"Iteration no. 6"
"Thread taking care of 5"
"Iteration no. 7"
"Thread taking care of 6"
"Iteration no. 8"
"Thread taking care of 7"
"Iteration no. 9"
"Thread taking care of 8"
"Iteration no. 10"
"Thread taking care of 9"
"Thread taking care of 10"
mt.rb:21:in `join': deadlock detected (fatal)
    from mt.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
    from mt.rb:21:in `each'
    from mt.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong, here? I've tried plenty of stuff, calling `Thread#join` instead of `Thread#stop`, not calling any `Thread` method at all when I'm done, etc.

Thanks in advance!

---

Revised code:

```
require 'thread'

ary = *0..10 

res = 0
mutex = Mutex.new

ary.each do |x|
    p "Iteration no. #{x}"
    t = Thread.new do
        p "Thread taking care of #{x}"
        mutex.synchronize do
            res += x
        end
        t.stop
    end
end

Thread.list.each &:join
puts res
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not [`stop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-stop) a thread while it is holding a mutex. The `stop` method puts the current thread into a sleeping state and schedules some other thread. Now, the first thread is holding the mutex so whichever other thread is scheduled next ends up waiting for the stopped thread to release the mutex which is never going to happen. Deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, this won't work. I've put the revised code at the end of the question. I'd love it if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

@FranciscoP.whatever you define in a loop remains local to the loop, you have called the thread in the loop it would not be available outside the loop, I think you should define a variable outside the loop and pass the thread into the variable, then the thread would be available for you when the loop is completed.

e.g:

```
threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
ary.each do |x|
    p "Iteration no. #{x}"
        mutex.synchronize do
            res += x
        end
end
threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the variable t inside of the thread. Try using Thread.stop, indicating the current thread. As in:

```
require 'thread'

ary = *0..10 

res = 0
mutex = Mutex.new

ary.each do |x|
    p "Iteration no. #{x}"
    t = Thread.new do
        p "Thread taking care of #{x}"
        mutex.synchronize do
            res += x
        end
        Thread.stop
    end
end

Thread.list.each &:join
puts res
```

Also I don't know if you will be able to join stopped threads. Why not reactivating then before the join?

```
Thread.list.each {|t| t.run; t.join }
puts res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do Thread.list.join because this list include main thread.

If you do Thread.main.join it raises error because you are waiting yourself and that's nonsense.

You could do:

```
Thread.list.delete_if { |t| t == Thread.main }.map(&:join)
```